# R - grouping values by identifying pattern in a column

Tags: r

I have a column of data,

`A<-c("no", "no", "yes","yes","yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no")`

I want to identify groups in this data where a "no", followed by any amount of "yes", represent one group. The next "no" value represents the start of a new group. I would like to end up with another column, B, that identifies these different groups by number, like:

```
    A B
1  no 1
2  no 2
3 yes 2
4 yes 2
5 yes 2
6  no 3
7  no 4
8 yes 4
9  no 5
```

It would also be ok if just "no" values and their associated "yes" values were numbered and other entries remained NA. A character identifier would also be ok, rather than a number. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `cumsum(A == "no")`